# Another FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN in android programming

Tags: java, android, exception, program-entry-point

I looked up other similar questions and couldn't find a solution, so here I am.
I am a complete beginner in Java and android programming, even though I have a quite good knowledge of C and basic knowledge of C++ and Python, as well as a few more specific programs like Mathematica and ROOT.

I tried making an extremely simple android app: a number displayed and two buttons which raise or decrease the number, but I get tons of errors. If you kindly have time to help me, I feel really discouraged by this first impact.

**This is my .xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@style/AppTheme"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartActivity" >


    <TextView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bSub"
         android:layout_width="250sp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="@string/button2"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/bAdd"
         android:layout_width="250sp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDisplay"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:text="@string/button1"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is my .java file:**

```
package com.appdiprova.giovanni;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    int counter; 
    Button add,sub;
    TextView display;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        counter=0;
        add= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter=counter+1;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter=counter-1;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

As I run the program I get in the LogCat a long list of errors, the first of which tells me FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN.

How can I solve this? 
Thank you very much

**EDIT**
I'm sorry, I'll post also the manifest and the LogCat

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appdiprova.giovanni"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.appdiprova.giovanni.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ok I am fairly confused, since now I don't get FATAL ECEPTION anymore, but still a lot of errors:

```
11-15 08:39:35.410: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.410: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.420: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.420: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.420: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.420: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.420: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.420: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.430: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.430: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.430: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.430: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.450: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.450: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.450: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.450: I/ActivityManager(370): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.appdiprova.giovanni/.StartActivity} from pid 546
11-15 08:39:35.460: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.460: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.470: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.470: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.470: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-15 08:39:35.470: W/AudioService(370): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
11-15 08:39:35.560: E/gralloc_goldfish(50): gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 246 x 410, usage 333
11-15 08:39:35.560: W/GraphicBufferAllocator(50): alloc(246, 410, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
11-15 08:39:35.560: E/(50): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=246, h=410) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
11-15 08:39:35.560: E/BufferQueue(370): [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
11-15 08:39:35.570: W/WindowManager(370): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
11-15 08:39:35.780: D/LightsService(370): Excessive delay setting light: 392ms
11-15 08:39:35.850: D/dalvikvm(924): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-15 08:39:35.870: I/ActivityManager(370): Start proc com.appdiprova.giovanni for activity com.appdiprova.giovanni/.StartActivity: pid=924 uid=10051 gids={50051}
11-15 08:39:36.610: D/AndroidRuntime(924): Shutting down VM
11-15 08:39:36.610: W/dalvikvm(924): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad1b90)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924): Process: com.appdiprova.giovanni, PID: 924
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appdiprova.giovanni/com.appdiprova.giovanni.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.appdiprova.giovanni.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:20)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  ... 11 more
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  ... 23 more
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060001 a=-1 r=0x7f060001}
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3545)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3475)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
11-15 08:39:36.630: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  ... 26 more
11-15 08:39:36.650: W/ActivityManager(370):   Force finishing activity com.appdiprova.giovanni/.StartActivity
11-15 08:39:37.050: I/WindowManager(370): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b40edef0 ActivityRecord{b40edd90 u0 com.appdiprova.giovanni/.StartActivity t3 f}} appWin=Window{b41b27f0 u0 Starting com.appdiprova.giovanni} drawState=4
11-15 08:39:37.050: W/WindowManager(370): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (480x800) to layer 21010
11-15 08:39:37.560: W/ActivityManager(370): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b40edd90 u0 com.appdiprova.giovanni/.StartActivity t3 f}
11-15 08:39:37.900: W/EGL_emulation(546): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-15 08:39:38.640: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.640: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.640: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.640: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.640: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.650: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.650: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.650: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.650: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.650: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.680: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.680: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.710: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.710: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.720: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.720: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.720: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.720: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.730: E/SoundPool(370): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.730: W/AudioService(370): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
11-15 08:39:38.730: W/AudioService(370): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
11-15 08:39:38.800: I/Process(924): Sending signal. PID: 924 SIG: 9
11-15 08:39:38.800: W/InputMethodManagerService(370): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b41dee38 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b4048d78
11-15 08:39:38.830: I/ActivityManager(370): Process com.appdiprova.giovanni (pid 924) has died.
11-15 08:39:42.300: D/MobileDataStateTracker(370): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
11-15 08:39:43.530: E/NetdConnector(370): NDC Command {47 bandwidth setiquota eth0 9223372036854775807} took too long (782ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat?

Comment: This code seems to be in order. Did you declare the activity in your Manifest xml?

Comment: Logcat gives you a very good explanation of why things don't work, so if you keep reading past the FATAL EXCEPTION it will tell you why, I'm guessing you haven't declared your activity in your manifest because the code do look in order as previously mentioned

Comment: Try cleaning your project, "Project --> Clean..." it says the problem is with your `RelativeLayout` but it looks ok to me

Comment: I'm not sure if it's mandatory, but normally your xml starts with something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `android:background` property of your `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:background="@style/AppTheme"
```

Android tells you

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060001 a=-1 r=0x7f060001}
```

The system expects the `background` resource to be a `Drawable`, not a style. Use `style` to set a style, or `android:background` to set a `Drawable` to be used as the background:

```
style="@style/AppTheme"
```

**Update:** From [the docs about `android:background`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground):

> A drawable to use as the background. This can be either a reference to
>   a full drawable resource (such as a PNG image, 9-patch, XML state list
>   description, etc), or a solid color such as "#ff000000" (black).

You can read more about styles and themes in the [Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem, even though it looks a bit bad for now! I was just confused because I followed a tutorial and the guy's program worked without any problem

Comment: @user2992124 Glad to have helped! Accept the answer if it helped you :)