# unknown exception when i run the application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

When I run my application, which is just an activity that calls another by pressing button, I get this exception.

The exception says something about an imageview although I don't have such a view in my xml.

Here is the exception:

```
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.williamromatest.testnavigationbar/com.williamromatest.testnavigationbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at com.williamromatest.testnavigationbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    ... 11 more
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    ... 22 more
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005b a=-1}
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1692)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:122)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
12-22 12:47:51.412: E/AndroidRuntime(22167):    ... 25 more
```

here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button b_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_button1);
        b_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b_button1:
            Intent intentToFirstActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    FirstAcitivty.class);
            startActivity(intentToFirstActivity);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

my xml layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout xml file please.

Comment: Which time error is coming When app starting load or you are pressing button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOLVED Another FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN in android programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002117/solved-another-fatal-exception-main-in-android-programming)

Comment: We need the XML file used in the `ComponentInfo` activity. The problem is there.

Comment: post the xml layout used in FirstActivity class...

Comment: @Melquiades i posted the xml

Comment: @Sanket990 i got the exception when i run immediately the application.

Comment: @blackbelt i dont have a drawable in my xml, please check the xml.

Comment: @still_learning i posted the xml file. plesae check it

Comment: I think build tools prblm plz check project-clean after again run this..

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seems any issue with your. I suggest you to just clean your project once and generate let it generate R.java file.